# Unable to ingest JSON data into Azure Event Hub

Tags: powershell, azure-eventhub

I wrote the below Powershell script to get the JSON data from an API endpoint (https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/vh2v-4nfs) and then write this data in JSON format to Azure Event hub. I am able to successfully get the data from the endpoint however the data is not getting ingested into Azure Event Hub.

Can anyone please let me know what's wrong with the below code:

```
$url = "https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/vh2v-4nfs"
$apptoken = "k7lQcUCVFoROv7rQh9fSSXMkZ"

# Set header to accept JSON
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept","application/json")
$headers.Add("X-App-Token",$apptoken)

$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method get -Headers $headers

$results


$method = "POST"
$URI = "https://YOURNS.servicebus.windows.net/eh-streetparking/messages"
$signature = "SharedAccessSignature sr=YOURNS.servicebus.windows.net%2feh-streetparking&sig=K6bfL1VjW9FUcL0B5xaI%3d&se=16722&skn=eh-sap-streetparking"

#$authInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$signature"))

# API headers
$headers = @{
            "Authorization"=$signature;
#            "Content-Type"="application/json;type=entry;charset=utf-8";
            "Content-Type"="application/json";
            }


# execute the Azure REST API

foreach ( $result in $results)
{
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $result
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you have presented as the return result from your `Invoke-RestMethod` is actually a **deserialized PowerShell object, not JSON**. It appears to be having its quotes removed at some point too.

PSObject (`$results`) looks like this: `$x = @{account_id="12345"; username="12345"; is_locked="False"; employee_id="12345"; first_name="John"; middle_initial="Roger"; last_name="Doe"; full_name="John Roger Doe"}`

You can do this to access individual values:

```
$x.full_name
```

Finally, follow [this syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-7#example-2--run-a-post-request) to send `POST` request:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Url = "https://server.contoso.com:8089/services/search/jobs/export"
$Body = @{
    search = "search index=_internal | reverse | table index,host,source,sourcetype,_raw"
    output_mode = "csv"
    earliest_time = "-2d@d"
    latest_time = "-1d@d"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -OutFile output.csv
```

Comment: How to serialize it back to JSON? Also, are there better scripts to achieve this and I am open to use any other script like C# or any other language if it helps to ingest the file in JSON format only. Please share me any pointers or relevant samples.

Comment: I went past the coverting to JSON using ConvertTo-Json utility and now it is failing with "Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

Comment: Another question has been raised for this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64778754/powershell-invoke-restmethod-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-413-reques