# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: json, azure, powershell

This is in continuation to "Unable to ingest JSON data into Azure Event Hub" issue raised by me.

I wrote the below powershell script to get the JSON data from an API endpoint and then move this data without any format change to Azure Event Hub. When I run this I am getting the below error:

```
$url = "https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/vh2v-4nfs"
$apptoken = "n8lQcUZROasdh9fSSMuV"

# Set header to accept JSON
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept","application/json")
$headers.Add("X-App-Token",$apptoken)

$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method get -Headers $headers

$resultsJSON = $results | ConvertTo-Json

#Write-Host $results

$method = "POST"
$URI = "https://EHNS.servicebus.windows.net/eh-streetparking/messages"
$signature = "SharedAccessSignature sr=EH.servicebus.windows.net%2feh-streetparking&sig=erTfoeVLiWrOk9aDsU%3d&se=1605994&skn=eh-sap-streetparking"


# API headers
$headers = @{
            "Authorization"=$signature;
#            "Content-Type"="application/json;type=entry;charset=utf-8";
            "Content-Type"="application/json";
            }


# create Request Body

# execute the Azure REST API

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $resultsJSON
```

#Error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
At C:\Users\User1 - \Scripts\get_mel_streetparking_data.ps1:37 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

How do I resolve this error? Are there any better scripting language and/or practices which I can adopt while writing above sort of scripts?

Comment: May I know the size of your JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for Service Bus, [Maximum message size: 256 KB for Standard tier, 1 MB for Premium tier.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas#messaging-quotas)

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar experience. I consulted several documents, including this one, but the issue was not resolved. However, I later found out that there was a problem with my code, fixed it, and error 413 no longer occurred. In the API I used, only header information should have been sent when using Invoke-WebRequest, but a problem occurred because body information was also sent. Even if the body was accidentally transmitted up to a certain size, there was no error, but as the body grew, error 413 occurred. So it was difficult to quickly find out that my code was the problem. Although it is not directly related, I am leaving this post so that others can also refer to it.